# Image size changes when position is fixed

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to fix an emoji-panel at the `bottom right corner` whose width and height is relative to screen width.
When `position` is `not fixed`,it works correctly (first image).
But when the `position` becomes `fixed`,both the background panel and emojis (img) inside it changes weirdly(second image).

[image: Before fixed]
[image: After fixed]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    .panel{
                /*position:fixed;*/
                     bottom: 0;
                     right: 0;
                     width:100%;
                     height:7%;
                     background-color:#dbd9d3;
                     border:1px solid black;
                }
         .panel_emojis{
                width: 14%;
                height: 14%;
                margin-right: 1.1%;
                margin-left: 1.1%;
                }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="panel">
<img src="emoji.png" class="panel_emojis" />
<img src="emoji.png" class="panel_emojis" />
<img src="emoji.png" class="panel_emojis" />
<img src="emoji.png" class="panel_emojis" />
<img src="emoji.png" class="panel_emojis" />
<img src="emoji.png" class="panel_emojis" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to move it to bottom right without affecting size of background and images inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude You just Needed to remove height to make the emoji img look perfect
I have edited your code as per your convenience.
I have removed the height so that the container (in this case panel) could change its shape according to the img inside it

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    .panel{
                position: fixed;
                     bottom: 0;
                     right: 0;
                     width:100%;
                     /* height:10%; */
                     background-color:#dbd9d3;
                     border:1px solid black;
                }
         .panel_emojis{
                width: 14%;
                height: 14%;
                margin-right: 1.1%;
                margin-left: 1.1%;
                }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="panel">
<img src="emoji.png" class="panel_emojis" />
<img src="emoji.png" class="panel_emojis" />
<img src="emoji.png" class="panel_emojis" />
<img src="emoji.png" class="panel_emojis" />
<img src="emoji.png" class="panel_emojis" />
<img src="emoji.png" class="panel_emojis" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If You don't want to remove the height | You can also change your panel_emoji height to `height: 100%;` so that your img could use the full height of your container (in this case panel) | to show you here is the code in which i have not removed the panel height , i just adjusted the panel_emoji height and that also just works fine
[Note:- i have increased the panel height so the whole img could be visible]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    .panel{
                position: fixed;
                     bottom: 0;
                     right: 0;
                     width:100%;
                     height:25%;
                     background-color:#dbd9d3;
                     border:1px solid black;
                }
         .panel_emojis{
                width: 14%;
                height: 100%;
                margin-right: 1.1%;
                margin-left: 1.1%;
                }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="panel">
<img src="emoji.jpg" class="panel_emojis" />
<img src="emoji.jpg" class="panel_emojis" />
<img src="emoji.jpg" class="panel_emojis" />
<img src="emoji.jpg" class="panel_emojis" />
<img src="emoji.jpg" class="panel_emojis" />
<img src="emoji.jpg" class="panel_emojis" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my suggestion You should add padding to your emoji image so that it could look pretty decent. Also You should not use `%` to give the `height` and `width` of the img.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `fixed` with `flex`:

> `flex` has come for these kind of purposes, a perfect layout where you can use the `flex` for responsiveness which works well.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/3ogu52eh/) to playaround.

```css
.panel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  background-color: #dbd9d3;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.panel_emojis {
  width: 14%;
  height: 14%;
  margin-right: 1.1%;
  margin-left: 1.1%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="panel">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" class="panel_emojis" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" class="panel_emojis" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" class="panel_emojis" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" class="panel_emojis" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" class="panel_emojis" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" class="panel_emojis" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
body{
   position: relative; 
}

.panel { 
   position: absolute; 
   bottom: 0; 
   right: 0; 
   width:100%; 
   height:7%; 
   background-color:#dbd9d3; 
   border:1px solid black; 
} 
.panel_emojis{ 
   width: 14%; 
   height: 14%; 
   margin-right: 1.1%; 
   margin-left: 1.1%; 
}
```

I did not change any sizing but I strongly suggest not to use percentages to set margins. I would also set the width/height of the emojis to a fixed px width & height instead of percentages.

Comment: Thanks! How should I set the margins? If I set the emoji's height and width to fixed px,how to make them responsive?

Comment: Set the `.panel` `display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:space-between;` which will spread all emojis to the width of the body unevenly.

Comment: You can check out as well instead of `justify-content: space-between;` try `space-around` or `space-evenly;` choose one that looks best to you

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be good if you add `display: flex` to the `.panel` to center the items inside easily. Problem of yours when using `position: fixed` is you didn't set height for the `.panel`, so the `.panel_emojis` which is effected by `height` of the parent `.panel` would be looked weird because you set `width` and `height` by percent. I don't think you should overuse `%` for setting if you don't know what exactly you want to do, use `px` instead.

Hope it would help you. Please correct me if I were wrong

```css
.panel{
  position:fixed;
  display: flex; /* use display: flex; justify-content for auto margin the item inside .panel */
  justify-content: space-between;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#dbd9d3;
  border:1px solid black;
}

/* Instead of using width, height in .panel_emojis, leave those two attributes to default (auto) */
.panel_emojis{
  // width: 14%;
  // height: 14%;
  margin-right: 1.1%;
  margin-left: 1.1%;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="panel">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120" class="panel_emojis" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120" class="panel_emojis" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120" class="panel_emojis" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120" class="panel_emojis" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120" class="panel_emojis" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120" class="panel_emojis" />
</div>
</body>
```